# How to iterate over list of Objects in struts 2

Tags: struts2

I am new to struts2 and facing one issue.

I have following datastructure.

```
class Employee extends actionsupport{

Private List<Address> address;


....getters and setters
}

class Address {
private String street_name;
Private City_name;
......and so on 

... getters and setters

}
```

how to iterate over this list in JSP using `<s:iterate>` tag. I tried many combination but some way it is not working for me.

Comment: IMO a collection should be named with a plural name (e.g., addresses). This makes thing much easier to think about. Also, even when just describing a problem, it's best to use proper syntax and naming.

Comment: @DaveNewton Did you intentionally say the singular "thing"?  Pretty funny.

Comment: @rees I did ;) Some of my commentary is subtle--thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way is to use Struts2 [iterator](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/iterator.html) tag which needs to provide collection as a data-source to iterator over.

```
<s:iterator value="address">
  <s:property value="street_name"/>
  <s:property value="City_name"/>
  //so on
</s:iterator>
```

When Iterator will iterator over the address it will place the object (Address in your case) on the top of value stack and you can refer to these properties directly as described above

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:iterator value="%{address}" var="addr">
    <s:property value="%{street_name}"/>
    <s:property value="#addr.street_name"/>
</s:iterator>
```